# Make an array an optional parameter for a c++ function

Tags: c++

In c++, you can make a parameter optional like this:

```
void myFunction(int myVar = 0);
```

How do you do that with an array?

```
void myFunction(int myArray[] = /*What do I put here?*/);
```

Comment: You could do something like `int myArrayDefault[] = {1,2,3};  void myFunction(int * myArray = myArrayDefault);`

Comment: Note that the definition is no different than `void myFunction(int *myArray)`.  You are not passing an array.

Comment: In C++, an array can't really be a parameter. You can have a pointer to element, reference to array, or pointer to array. But not an array.

Comment: Why not use `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default argument must have static linkage (e.g. be a global).
Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

int array[] = {100, 1, 2, 3};

void myFunction(int myArray[] = array)
{
    std::cout << "First value of array is: " << myArray[0] << std::endl;
    // Note that you cannot determine the length of myArray!
}

int main()
{
    myFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use a `nullptr` or a pointer to a global const array to denote the default value:

```
void myFunction(int myArray[] = nullptr ) {
                             // ^^^^^^^
}
```

This is because `int myArray[]` is type adjusted to a `int*` pointer when used as function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If the *default* array is small enough (note: it can be smaller than the size of the actual array type), so that copying it is not an issue, then (since C++11) `std::array` is probably the most expressive, "C++-ish" style (as Ed Heal hinted in a comment). Apart from the copy-init burden on each argument-less `f()` call, using the default, the array itself has the same performance properties as built-in C-like arrays, but it doesn't need an awkward, separately defined default variable:

```
#include <array>

// Just for convenience:
typedef std::array<int, 3> my_array;

void f(const my_array& a = {1, 2, 3});
```

(NOTE: passing by const ref. avoids the copy at least for those cases, where you do pass an argument explicitly.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in modern C++ 17 you can use `std::optional`.

```
std::optional<std::array<int,4>> oa;

// ...

if ( oa )
{
    // there is content in oa
    *oa // get the content
}
else
{
    // there is no content inside oa
}
```

I used `std::array` as my representation of the array but you could just as well use raw arrays, vectors, whatever.