# I don't know how to make this function

Tags: c++, arrays, function-parameter

### Original question

I am writing a function called `Evaluate` in C++. It accepts three arrays as parameters:

```cpp
double Evaluate (double inputs[], double hidden[], double outputs[]) {
    // To-Do...
}
```

The problem appears in this *scenario*:

> The programmer decides to initialize the function `Evaluate` with only two parameters: inputs[] and outputs.

So, I was thinking of creating `Evaluate` like this:

```cpp
double Evaluate (double inputs[], double hidden[] = {}, double outputs[]) {
    // To-Do...
}
```

But, this creates strange Errors:

```cpp
  In function 'double Evaluate (double*, double*, double*)'
34:53: error: unexpected '{' token
34:54: error: unexpected '}' token
```

Is there a solution?

*Thanks in advance.

### Updated question

I have managed to use my answer with the help in the comments.

I am currently curious, won't multiple function overloads cause the program to get slower?

Comment: Replace all of those arguments with `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an array an optional parameter for a c++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761243/make-an-array-an-optional-parameter-for-a-c-function) **Also note that optional parameters must come after mandatory parameters**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way which I have learnt is *function overloading* - where you create copy of the same function, but in different ways.

```
int add(int a)
{
    return ++a;
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

double add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

This became so helpful that I'm able to implement many operations with it!

In terms of my `evaluate` function, I could do:

```
evaluate(std::vector<double> inputs, std::vector<double> outputs, std::vector<double> hidden)
{
    // ...
}

evaluate (std::vector<double> inputs, std::vector<double> outputs)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What?  How does this answer in any way relate to your original question?  The fact remains that you cannot have non-default arguments appearing after default arguments, and you cannot default-initialize an array argument with `{}`

Comment: I have been testing function overloading to see if will help. The function evaluate would recieve three or two parameters. It there is no `hidden` parameter, then it would used the default hidden configuration. The example above is very minimal.

Comment: The point is that if you had instead defined your function as `double Evaluate(double inputs[], double outputs[], double hidden[] = nullptr)` you would have only required a single definition.